# Magento InfiniteScroll not working with AheadWorks Layered Navigation

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, ajax, infinte-scroll

I am using https://github.com/Strategery-Inc/Magento-InfiniteScroll extesion for infinite scroll with porto + AheadWorks Layered Navigation 
It's stops working when we apply any sorting?
Do you have any idea how to resolve it.

Comment: You should contact the support from Aheadworks (or Porto or Infinite scroll extension). You can also build your own infinite scroll.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh my support period has been ended, is there any resource to build out our own infinite scroll